# How does one manually compute the error of the whole data set in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I was trying to track the error of the whole data set and compute the error of the whole data set in pytorch. I wrote the following (reproducible example and fully contained) in cifar10 pytorch 0.3.1:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.optim as optim

import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

from math import inf

from pdb import set_trace as st

def error_criterion(outputs,labels):
    max_vals, max_indices = torch.max(outputs,1)
    train_error = (max_indices != labels).sum().data[0]/max_indices.size()[0]
    return train_error

def evalaute_mdl_data_set(loss,error,net,dataloader,enable_cuda,iterations=inf):
    '''
    Evaluate the error of the model under some loss and error with a specific data set.
    '''
    running_loss,running_error = 0,0
    for i,data in enumerate(dataloader):
        if i >= iterations:
            break
        inputs, labels = extract_data(enable_cuda,data,wrap_in_variable=True)
        outputs = net(inputs)
        running_loss += loss(outputs,labels).data[0]
        running_error += error(outputs,labels)
    return running_loss/(i+1),running_error/(i+1)

def extract_data(enable_cuda,data,wrap_in_variable=False):
    inputs, labels = data
    if enable_cuda:
        inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda() #TODO potential speed up?
    if wrap_in_variable:
        inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)
    return inputs, labels

def train_and_track_stats(enable_cuda, nb_epochs, trainloader,testloader, net,optimizer,criterion,error_criterion, iterations=inf):
    ''' Add stats before training '''
    train_loss_epoch, train_error_epoch = evalaute_mdl_data_set(criterion, error_criterion, net, trainloader, enable_cuda, iterations)
    test_loss_epoch, test_error_epoch = evalaute_mdl_data_set(criterion, error_criterion, net, testloader, enable_cuda, iterations)
    print(f'[-1, -1], (train_loss: {train_loss_epoch}, train error: {train_error_epoch}) , (test loss: {test_loss_epoch}, test error: {test_error_epoch})')
    ##
    ''' Start training '''
    print('about to start training')
    for epoch in range(nb_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
        running_train_loss,running_train_error = 0.0,0.0
        for i,data_train in enumerate(trainloader):
            ''' zero the parameter gradients '''
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            ''' train step = forward + backward + optimize '''
            inputs, labels = extract_data(enable_cuda,data_train,wrap_in_variable=True)
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_train_loss += loss.data[0]
            running_train_error += error_criterion(outputs,labels)
        ''' End of Epoch: collect stats'''
        train_loss_epoch, train_error_epoch = running_train_loss/(i+1), running_train_error/(i+1)
        #train_loss_epoch, train_error_epoch = evalaute_mdl_data_set(criterion,error_criterion,net,trainloader,enable_cuda,iterations)
        test_loss_epoch, test_error_epoch = evalaute_mdl_data_set(criterion,error_criterion,net,testloader,enable_cuda,iterations)
        print(f'[{epoch}, {i+1}], (train_loss: {train_loss_epoch}, train error: {train_error_epoch}) , (test loss: {test_loss_epoch}, test error: {test_error_epoch})')
    return train_loss_epoch, train_error_epoch, test_loss_epoch, test_error_epoch

class Flatten(torch.nn.Module):
    def forward(self, input):
        return input.view(input.size(0), -1)

def main():
    enable_cuda = True
    print('running main')
    num_workers = 0
    ''' Get Data set '''
    batch_size_test = 10000
    batch_size_train = 10000
    data_path = './data'
    transform = [transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize( (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) )]
    transform = transforms.Compose(transform)
    trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root=data_path, train=True,download=False, transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size_train,shuffle=True, num_workers=num_workers)
    testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root=data_path, train=False,download=False, transform=transform)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size_test,shuffle=False, num_workers=num_workers)
    ''' Get model '''
    net = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Conv2d(3,13,5), #(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size),
        Flatten(),
        torch.nn.Linear(28*28*13, 13),
        torch.nn.Linear(13, 10)
    )
    net.cuda()
    ''' Train '''
    nb_epochs = 10
    lr = 0.1
    err_criterion = error_criterion
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=lr, momentum=0.0)
    train_and_track_stats(enable_cuda, nb_epochs, trainloader,testloader, net,optimizer,criterion,err_criterion, iterations=inf)
    ''' Done '''
    print('Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
python my_cifar10.py
running main
[-1, -1], (train_loss: 2.3172860145568848, train error: 0.0054) , (test loss: 2.317185878753662, test error: 0.0038)
about to start training
[0, 5], (train_loss: 2.22599835395813, train error: 0.015160000000000002) , (test loss: 2.0623881816864014, test error: 0.0066)
[1, 5], (train_loss: 2.014406657218933, train error: 0.00896) , (test loss: 1.9619578123092651, test error: 0.0195)
[2, 5], (train_loss: 1.9428715705871582, train error: 0.01402) , (test loss: 1.918603539466858, test error: 0.0047)
[3, 5], (train_loss: 1.9434458494186402, train error: 0.01192) , (test loss: 1.9194672107696533, test error: 0.0125)
[4, 5], (train_loss: 1.8804980754852294, train error: 0.00794) , (test loss: 1.8549214601516724, test error: 0.004)
[5, 5], (train_loss: 1.8573726177215577, train error: 0.010159999999999999) , (test loss: 1.8625996112823486, test error: 0.0158)
[6, 5], (train_loss: 1.8454653739929199, train error: 0.01524) , (test loss: 1.8155865669250488, test error: 0.0122)
[7, 5], (train_loss: 1.8140610456466675, train error: 0.01066) , (test loss: 1.808283805847168, test error: 0.0101)
[8, 5], (train_loss: 1.8036894083023072, train error: 0.00832) , (test loss: 1.799634575843811, test error: 0.007)
[9, 5], (train_loss: 1.8023016452789307, train error: 0.0077399999999999995) , (test loss: 1.8030155897140503, test error: 0.0114)
Done
```

Clearly it has to be wrong cuz the test error is nearly zero with a model that is ridiculously small and simple (1 conv 2 fcs).

the code seems so simple that I can't figure out what is going wrong. I've been doing stuff and changing things for a few days now. Any new suggestions what to try?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I was just testing on cpu and got `[-1, -1], (train_loss: 2.3224891445520894, train error: 0.8735254156010229) , (test loss: 2.3210103873965107, test error: 0.8691653481012658)
about to start training
[0, 391], (train_loss: 1.8232954066732656, train error: 0.6340393222506394) , (test loss: 1.7517535837390754, test error: 0.6045292721518988) ...`. The loss makes sense:  If you have 10 classes with random guessing you will be right ~ 1/10 of the time resulting in a crossentropy loss of `ln(-1/10) = 2.3`. So the error should be in the `error_criterion` function.

Comment: I coud not reproduce before, because I changed the batch size to 128

Comment: @McLawrence it seems to be an overflow error cuz of byte tensor or something. Related post: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-the-cifar10-tutorial-make-sure-to-use-the-test-set-is-actually-the-test-set-if-both-use-the-same-path-to-load-both-test-and-train/16288 thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your batch size is too large, with your code the values of

```
(max_indices == labels).sum()
(max_indices != labels).sum()
```

do not add up to the batch size. This is due to the fact, that you use a `torch.ByteTensor` which will overflow for values > 255 when summing.

using

```
(max_indices != labels).int().sum()
```

will resolve the issue by casting the Tensor to `int` before summing.

Comment: interesting! makes me feel that perhaps this is not the standard way to compute the error of a model? Do you know what is the standard way? I also assume that its not the fastest? Why do I need to do all this re-casting business?

Comment: what does `.init()` do?

Comment: @CharlieParker: I think your way of computing the error is a legitimate way. Which `.init()`do you mean? do you mean `.int()`?

Comment: oh! Yea I mean `.int()`

Comment: `.int()` just recasts the tensor to `int`. It is not important if you cast to `int` or `float` here (as you did in your answer) because in `python3` division between two integers results in a float.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense now! :D Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

As one solution on [pytorch forum suggested](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-the-cifar10-tutorial-make-sure-to-use-the-test-set-is-actually-the-test-set-if-both-use-the-same-path-to-load-both-test-and-train/16288/11) a good idea is to recast things:

```
def error_criterion(outputs,labels):
    max_vals, max_indices = torch.max(outputs,1)
    train_error = (max_indices != labels).float().sum()/max_indices.size()[0]
    return train_error
```

The comparision `(max_indices != labels)` returns a `torch.ByteTensor`, which can overflow using your batch size of `10000`.
Adding a `.float`to this line `(max_indices != labels).float().sum()` seems to make things go away.

Things seem fine now:

```
$ python my_cifar10.py
running main
[-1, -1], (train_loss: 2.3301061153411866, train error: 0.9383399844169616) , (test loss: 2.3303537368774414, test error: 0.9396999478340149)
about to start training
[0, 5], (train_loss: 2.1861009120941164, train error: 0.8279399871826172) , (test loss: 2.044313907623291, test error: 0.7494999766349792)
[1, 5], (train_loss: 2.009986090660095, train error: 0.7244199872016907) , (test loss: 1.9966429471969604, test error: 0.7224999666213989)
[2, 5], (train_loss: 2.0178127527236938, train error: 0.712559974193573) , (test loss: 1.9238039255142212, test error: 0.6651999950408936)
[3, 5], (train_loss: 1.9113547801971436, train error: 0.6625399827957154) , (test loss: 1.8861572742462158, test error: 0.6486999988555908)
[4, 5], (train_loss: 1.8807836771011353, train error: 0.6485799789428711) , (test loss: 1.8632378578186035, test error: 0.6452999711036682)
[5, 5], (train_loss: 1.8648049116134644, train error: 0.6440199613571167) , (test loss: 1.875121831893921, test error: 0.652999997138977)
[6, 5], (train_loss: 1.8700860738754272, train error: 0.6511399745941162) , (test loss: 1.830731987953186, test error: 0.633899986743927)
[7, 5], (train_loss: 1.8432915449142455, train error: 0.6376399874687195) , (test loss: 1.8518757820129395, test error: 0.6491999626159668)
[8, 5], (train_loss: 1.830060887336731, train error: 0.634719979763031) , (test loss: 1.7997492551803589, test error: 0.6247000098228455)
[9, 5], (train_loss: 1.8012208938598633, train error: 0.6230199933052063) , (test loss: 1.8045140504837036, test error: 0.628600001335144)
Done
```